# Changes to top bar

Tags: sharepoint-designer, navigation, css, top-link-bar

[image]

Hi guys,

I want to remove this Home -> Home thing next to logo throughout the site collection. This should also not appear even navigating to site settings.

Secondly, I want to add an image next to "I like it" button and I want to give it a link so that by clicking the image, user can open the new page in new window.

What would I need to change in order to achieve the above requirements?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have tried to hide it by editing Master Page with Deepu's code but no luck
Could not hide it completely....
Any other solution

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
 .ms-pagebreadcrumb
    {
    display:none;
    }
```

in your custom css and refer that in your master page

Adding a link next to "I Like It" would also require in customizing the master page, by adding an image with hyper link.

Comment: I treied .ms-pagebreadcrumb but it didn't hide Home->Home.
Any other solution?

Comment: Do your custom css have an "After" attribute? Follow this article to override css classes of corev4.css - http://sw1ma.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/css-registration-and-after-property/

Comment: It actually hid the first hid HOME but not the second HOME and the > sign in between two HOMEs

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your master page

Answer (score 0):

For the image next to "I like it" you can add a "td" right before the `<td class="s4-socialdata-notifi">` in your master page:

```
<td class="yourImageClass">
   <asp:Image ID="idforyourTag" runat="server" ImageUrl="_layouts/path/logo.png" />
</td>
```

Or if you host the picture in the sharepoint db:

```
 ImageUrl="<%$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/path/logo.png %>"
```

For hiding the breadcrumb do what Deepu Nair posted.

Answer (score 0):

Open the master page in SharePoint designer in edit mode. You can add\delete\edit elements on it as per your need.